# peg thunderbird to older version or install a second instance

Tags: debian, version, thunderbird, tor

I am thinking of trying the thunderbird add-on [torbirdy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy)

The problem is, it only works up to Thunderbird version 60.2.1 from October 2018. I am running Debian Buster which updates Thunderbird automatically and it's currently on 68.11.0

Is it worth somehow rolling back thunderbird to that version, and telling Debian to leave it alone? If so, how would that be done? Otherwise would it better to install the older version somehow alongside.

I wonder what can really be new in email, and what the constant updates to Thunderbird are actually updating. It has somehow become too incompatible with torbirdy for it to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following: uninstall the version offered by Debian, install the version offered by Mozilla itself, e.g. https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/60.2.1/ - just unpack a tar.gz to a directory of your choice.

It's advisable to use the latest stable release, e.g. 60.9.1 which should retain the same level of compatibility as 60.2.1 but even **60.9.1 has long been unsupported and contains known vulnerabilities**. It's generally **not** advisable to run unsupported software especially web browsers and desktop mail clients.

Comment: Thanks, but you make me think twice about actually doing this. Sounds like it answers the question however. Debian would probably leave that install alone. How does a desktop mail client manage to have vulnerabilities? Am guessing it is just that emails have javascript etc, if that was all switched off and it was text only, you might be able to use the same version for a long time without upgrading..

Comment: *How does a desktop mail client manage to have vulnerabilities?* Email messages parsing code is quite complex. Even "simple" HTML rendering can contain bugs.

Comment: Makes me feel tempted to switch to 'pine'..